# See a user's reputation *without* daily cap

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Is there a way to see what a user's total reputation would be if, hypothetically, there was never a daily rep cap?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) query that can calculate this based on a user's id.

[How much rep would I have if there were no rep cap?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/824/how-much-rep-would-i-have-if-there-were-no-rep-cap-fixed)

Comment: I managed to grab 5 different queries for this purpose but managed to overlook the one that gave exactly what was needed. Figures, and "rep no cap" doesn't even yield this in a search...

Comment: Ah, I searched for "rep cap". (:

Comment: That said, the query is suspect. It claims my rep on Stack Overflow would be 1608, but I've never even been capped and my rep is 1466.

Comment: @GraceNote, Huh, so what isn't it handling I wonder?

Comment: @GraceNote, it won't be able to count the -1 on downvotes you cast, but from your profile, that isn't it.

Comment: I'm not an SQL expert, but from a quick glance at the query it doesn't differentiate between question upvotes and answer upvotes. And, consequently, the +2 for acceptance. It may need some major tweaking, perhaps with the aid of [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/683/top-rated-users-if-there-was-no-reputation-cap) or [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/872/top-rated-users-without-lost-reputation).

Comment: @GraceNote Oy, true.  I just took a cursory glance. q:

Comment: It also doesn't count bounties and doesn't appear to differentiate between wiki posts and regular posts.

Comment: @Pollyanna, it does check the OwnerId and CommunityOwnedDate.  Everything else I didn't catch I blame on not having had caffeine yet this morning!

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, but Jeff once said in a [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/daily-dose-of-daily-reputation-ca/) that Jon Skeet would have over 60,000 reputation without a cap.

And this was over 2 years ago.

Comment: I recently read that post, which is actually what prompted me to ask this.  Jon is currently at > a quarter million, which made me wonder what it would be today.  Oh well, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Adam Jon Skeet would be at a whopping 750,000 points without the rep cap.

Comment: Yeah - I saw.  If anything I'm surprised it's not over a million with the way his answers are (justifiably) upvoted.