# Measure reputation that's been thrown away

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

To date I've had 57 days where I've exceeded my reputation cap (including today). A few times I've wondered, "how much rep was thrown away today"? Not that I can do anything constructive with that, just for curiosity. The new reputation tab doesn't show how many upvotes, for example, were given for an answer that doesn't contribute to rep because of the cap:

[image: Visual of upvotes that didn't count]

So I just wonder if there is some place where this "lost rep" could be tabulated? Again, not because I would do anything useful with it, but just because I'm a data guy and this is interesting data.

(It would also be useful to see rep adjustments, such as when I down-vote an answer and then the answer gets deleted, all history disappears from my rep and activity; I'd rather see where I lost the point and then where I lost it back.)

Comment: [*Slow clap for exceeding the rep cap 57 days*](http://marks.dk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/slow-clap.gif)

Comment: Answers in here may help http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79521/see-a-users-reputation-without-daily-cap

Comment: @AdamRackis ah, interesting, thanks! As I was typing in the question I was hoping a duplicate would pop up, but I guess I didn't phrase the question right. Cheers/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So I just wonder if there is some place where this "lost rep" could be tabulated? Again, not because I would do anything useful with it, but just because I'm a data guy and this is interesting data.

Sure, but is it worth it?  My view would be a definite no...the reputation system is *very* complicated as it is, calculating, recalculating and tracking what *would have been* is even crazier, on top of the current crazy.

My view may be harsh here - sorry if it comes across that way, but if you were able to see the code and how many places this affects, I'm confident you'd agree.

> (It would also be useful to see rep adjustments, such as when I down-vote an answer and then the answer gets deleted, all history disappears from my rep and activity; I'd rather see where I lost the point and then where I lost it back.)

This already happens, if you check the checkbox at the bottom all of this is already visible, and on the correct dates, etc.

For example a -1 for a downvote would show at the time you voted, a +1 would show when the post was deleted.  If you are able to see the post (your own answer on a non-deleted question, or 10k+ rep) it will be linked, otherwise it's just text (since such a link would 404).

Comment: Thanks Nick, I never scrolled down far enough to see that checkbox. I know that it's there now, but I wonder if it could be made more prominent on a user's own reputation tab? I'm sure I'm not the only one who will be curious about this stuff but not see it...

Comment: @AaronBertrand it's *only* present on your reputation tab, and it's non-obvious by design.  You can read more about our approaches to this (thank Jeff!) here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion